# Django - Supervisor. Exited too quickly (process log may have details)

Tags: django, supervisord

When adding my application written in Django to Digitalocean, it gets the following code (on the step Configure Supervisor).

```
 my-app    FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

Why does it receive such an error when running the command '`sudo supervisorctl status my-app`' (to check if my server is working)?

**My my-app.conf**

```
[program:my-app]
command =sh /home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start
user = my-app
autostart = true
autorestart = true
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /home/my-app/env/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

**My gunicorn_start**

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME="my-app"
DIR=/home/my-app/my_app/app_rama
USER=app
GROUP=app
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/home/my-app/env/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app_rama.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=app_rama.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR
source ../bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

**My log**

```
/home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: 19: exec: ../bin/gunicorn: not found
/home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: 14: /home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: source: not found
/home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: 19: exec: ../bin/gunicorn: not found
/home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: 14: /home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: source: not found
/home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: 19: exec: ../bin/gunicorn: not found
/home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: 14: /home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: source: not found
/home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: 19: exec: ../bin/gunicorn: not found
```

**Basic directory**

```
/home/my-app (my env here)
/home/my-app/my_app/app_rama (manage.py)
/home/my-app/my_app/app_rama/app_rama (files here manage.py, wsgi, urls etc.)
/home/my-app/my_app/app_rama/app (files like template, urls_app etc.)
```

Comment: Can i see your gunicorn logs?

Comment: I added my current log above.

Comment: seems like you set the working directory wrong in `gunicorn_start` it cannot find the `bin` directory one level above of your current directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Did I understand correctly, I need to change it `source ../bin/activate` into: `source ../../bin/activate`. If it, I still receives an error `/home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: 14: /home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: source: not found
/home/my-app/env/bin/gunicorn_start: 19: exec: ../../gunicorn: not found`

Comment: This is incomprehensible to me, even if I give the absolute path I still do not get a positive result. 
`[...]
cd
source /home/my-app/env/bin/activate
[...]` instead 
`[...]
cd $DIR
source ../bin/activate
[...]` in my gunicorn_start file.